# Creating records in multiple models from one form with eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a form that captures users details and wish to save into two separate models: **contacts** and **contract_addresses**.

Below is the output from my  `$request->all()` from within the controller method:

```
{
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Jackson",
  "nickname": "JJ",
  "salutation": "Mr",
  "contact_address": {
    "phone_mobile": "123456789",
    "email": "jj@jackson.com",
    "address_1": "123 Office",
    "postcode": "2334",
    "address_2": "456 Lane",
    "province": "New Portia",
    "city": "Okalaville",
    "country": "Golubia"
  }
}
```

I have set up appropriate relationships in my models as follows:

**Contact Model:**

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Contact_address');
}
```

**Contact_Address Model:**

```
public function contact()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Contact');
}
```

**Controller Method:**
Here's how I have setup the controller method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $contact = new Contact($request->except("contact_address"));
    $contact_address = new Contact_address($request->contact_address);
    $contact->setRelation('address', $contact_address);
    $contact->push();
    return back();
}
```

**Errors with push():** The `push()` above throws 2 SQL exceptions:

**1/2 PDOException in Connection.php line 408:**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myappdb`.`contact_addresses`, CONSTRAINT `contact_addresses_contact_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`id`))
```

**2/2 QueryException in Connection.php line 673:**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`myappdb`.`contact_addresses`, CONSTRAINT `contact_addresses_contact_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `contact_address` (`phone_mobile`, `email`, `address_1`, `postcode`, `address_2`, `province`, `city`, `country`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (343434, , , , , , , , 2016-05-08 23:53:02, 2016-05-08 23:53:02))
```

I suspect that the problem seems to be that foreign key for the `contact.id` is not being passed through when performing the SQL insert for the addresses, even though the contact itself does get inserted into contacts table successfully.

How can I create a new record in both tables?

- Do I have to create the contact, retrieve the contact.id, then use that again to save the addresses?
- Is it better to remove sql foreign key constraint in my db?
- How would you structure this?

Comment: Why don't you store all your data in the `Contact` model, setting `contact_address` as a JSON column? That way you don't need additional models.

Comment: I don't think it's actually saved the Contact yet. Try changing your code to $contact = Contact::create($request->except("contact_address"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `save` method.

```
public function store(Request  $request) { 
 $contact = Contact::create($request->except(["contact_address"]));
 $contact_address = new Contact_address($request->get('contact_address'));
 $contact->contact_address()->save($contact_address); 
 return back();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abhishek - This did work, but with a small change.
The save() method accepts an eloquent model, and we are passing it an array. So adjusting the above to:

`$contact_address = new Contact_address($request->contact_address);
$contact = Contact::create($request->except("contact_address"));
$contact->addresses()->save($contact_address);`

Comment: Oops! my bad. Updated.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for taking time to answer and the update